# Machine Learning and stability of correlations

Tags: machine-learning, correlation

I need some help improving my understanding. As far as I know many (if not all) ML algorithms assume time stationarity, that means that the sampled distribution should not change over time.

On a bigger dataset that includes multiple days I see the correlatios to change significantly. For example during first hour Feature A and B have a correlation of 0.8. On second hour  their correlations drops to 0.2 or also goes to negative values.

Is not this also a problem? Is not assumed that the correlation of features should not change (at least not drastically) as more data comes into play?

If I am correct on that can you please provide me some more references to polish a bit my understanding but also go much deeper?

Thanks a lot your great help.
Regards
Alex

Comment: it is a fact that ML models *age* after a while, almost no real-world event is strictly stationary, so models based on real-world data age and need retraining

Comment: Data drifts over time. The hard part is finding when the drift effects the business decision from the model. The model might get a lower AUROC due to drift but the business decision from the model does not change since the change in AUROC was in an area of the decision that did not matter - e.g. a change in orders of a few observations that were all above the cut-off. Hence why statistical metrics are just one part, and often the small part, of developing a model.

Comment: I edited the question above to show that these changes happen more frequently, in hourly scale. Still what violations do you see ? I am looking some link on the hypotheses that typical machine learning algorithms rely on. Do they need constant correlations, do they need statonaritiy do they nixed fixed type of relations between the features?

Comment: ML models assume that the *window of data* given is stationary. For example one may try to fit a non-stationary process (eg by an RNN) by including a large range of the process as a window that indeed meets the stationarity criteria for the purpose needed

Comment: Dear Nikos thanks. Can you provide me some relevant references? So indeed change of correlations over that window of time is problematic